# Swift: Checking type of a dictionary value

Tags: swift, introspection

I would like to check the type of a dictionary value, and I use the following test code:

```
let swiftDict = [1: "one", 2: "two"]

if swiftDict[1] is NSString {
    println("it's an nsstring")
}
```

I got Compiler warning: "Cast from 'String?' to unrelated NSString always fails.

Modified the code to the following:

```
if let str = swiftDict[1] as? NSString? {
    println("it's an nsstring")
}
```

Now I get Compiler warning: Conditional cast from String? to NSString? always succeeds.

How do I fix the above warning? What's the right way to check for a variable type?

The reason for the check is to find out whether String or NSString is stored.

Comment: As you specifically work with swift types, I suggest you do `if swiftDict[1] is String`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to test your value type at all, as Swift is already type-safe?

Contrary to Objective-C, arrays and dictionaries in Swift are typed. So your `swiftDict` variable is of type `Dictionary<Int, String>` (or `[Int:String]` for short) and thus the values of this dictionary will always be `String`s, by definition.

For example, if you had tried to write this:

```
let swiftDict = [1: "one", 2: "two", 3: 7]
// error: '_' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

Then the compiler would error, telling you that 7 is not of type `String` nor convertible to a `String`, so you can't add it to `swiftDict`, which is inferred to be of type `[Int:String]`

This means that, by definition, `swiftDict[1]` will always be a `String` (because `swiftDict` is a `[Int:String]`)… or `nil` if there is no key `1` in that dict.

--> `swiftDict[1]` is guaranteed to be of type `String?`. So **you don't even need to test the type cast**. You just need to test if it's `nil` or not.

```
if let value = swiftDict[1] {
    println("swiftDict has a string value of \(value) for key 1")
} else {
    println("swiftDict does not have the key 1")
}
```

---

[EDIT] Also note that `String` and `NSString` are toll-free bridged, which means that they are totally interchangeable. So you don't even need to test or cast if your `String` is an `NSString`, as it will always be possible to cast from `String` to `NSString` and vice-versa (it will always be possible to interpret your string either as `String` or `NSString`).

Comment: I am checking to see if the type stored is NSString or String.  How do I achieve that?

Comment: `String` and `NSString` are toll-free bridged. So you can always convert a `String` to an `NSString` (provided you `import Foundation` at some point). So you don't even really need to cast it. But if you really want to explicitly cast it anyway, simply use `as` when the cast is know to always succeed (as opposed to `as?` or `as!` if it might fail. If `myString` is of type `String`, you can then write `myString as NSString`. If `myOptString` is of type `String?`, like `swiftDict[1]` is, you can simply `myOptString as NSString?` (`swiftDict[1] as NSString?`). No need for conditional cast.

Comment: I edited my answer to give more info about `String` vs `NSString`, but basically they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a dictionary with mixed types (i.e. value:AnyObject) you could iterate through them and use `is` to check what type a value in the dictionary is, e.g.

```
let swiftDict:[Int:AnyObject] = [1: "one", 2: "two", 3: 15, 4: true]
for (key, value) in swiftDict
{
    if (value is String)
    {
        println("\(key): \(value) is String")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `for (key, value) in swiftDict` to avoid having to unpack the `item` tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It wont matter if you cast it to string or NSString as its just a character sequence in the dictionary. Both will work. If it's a string in the dictionary, it's a String or an NSString, depending what you set it as.

```
if let str = swiftDict[1] as? String 
{
    println("it's a string")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**guard** could be used

```
guard let key = swiftDict[1] else {
    println("swiftDict does not have the key 1")
    return;
}
```